# Can't find element (findElement) in the Chrome browser using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I can't find the elements in Chrome browser(

> ng-bind="task.STATE">Documents<

Selenium can find the element only in FireFox browser (via Selenium IDE)

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[4]/span")).click();
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="stat-column">
          <h4><!-- <div class="dashboard-tasks-undone">{{numTasks}}</div>  --> <span class="dashboard-tasks-undone-text">Tasks</span></h4>
          <div class="tasks-panel row">
            <!-- ngRepeat: task in tasks --><div class="col-xs-4 tasks-panel-cell ng-scope" ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-click="kycTaskClick(task)">
              <span class="task-counter ng-binding task-counter-red" ng-bind="task.COUNT" ng-class="{'task-counter-faded': task.COUNT == '0','task-counter-red':task.red}">11</span>
              <span class="task-description ng-binding" ng-bind="task.STATE">Permission</span>
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: task in tasks --><div class="col-xs-4 tasks-panel-cell ng-scope" ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-click="kycTaskClick(task)">
              <span class="task-counter ng-binding" ng-bind="task.COUNT" ng-class="{'task-counter-faded': task.COUNT == '0','task-counter-red':task.red}">27</span>
              <span class="task-description ng-binding" ng-bind="task.STATE">Authorised</span>
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: task in tasks --><div class="col-xs-4 tasks-panel-cell ng-scope" ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-click="kycTaskClick(task)">
              <span class="task-counter ng-binding" ng-bind="task.COUNT" ng-class="{'task-counter-faded': task.COUNT == '0','task-counter-red':task.red}">95</span>
              <span class="task-description ng-binding" ng-bind="task.STATE">Answers</span>
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: task in tasks --><div class="col-xs-4 tasks-panel-cell ng-scope" ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-click="kycTaskClick(task)">
              <span class="task-counter ng-binding" ng-bind="task.COUNT" ng-class="{'task-counter-faded': task.COUNT == '0','task-counter-red':task.red}">47</span>
              <span class="task-description ng-binding" ng-bind="task.STATE">Documents</span>
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: task in tasks --><div class="col-xs-4 tasks-panel-cell ng-scope" ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-click="kycTaskClick(task)">
              <span class="task-counter ng-binding" ng-bind="task.COUNT" ng-class="{'task-counter-faded': task.COUNT == '0','task-counter-red':task.red}">14</span>
              <span class="task-description ng-binding" ng-bind="task.STATE">Identity</span>
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: task in tasks --><div class="col-xs-4 
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: are you performing similar CLICK action in selenium IDE? Have you tried other locators identified by Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below xpaths

//span[contains(text(),'Documents')]

//div[@class='stat-column']/div/div[4]/span[2]

//div[@class='stat-column']/div/div[4]/span[@ng-bind='task.STATE']

and few more also possible..

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! The main problem was in resizing window. Dashboard slid down and for some reason selenium could not find elements.

Comment: ok..good to know as got out off problem.. generally i will use maximize after starting browser which fits the screen.. will get less issues like this

Comment: 1) about first xpath: //span[contains(text(),'Documents')]
 -> please make sure that we don't have any "Documents" text in DOM
2) Also you can use xpath like this: //span[@ng-bind='task.STATE' and .//text()[contains(.,"Documents")]]